# dotnet pack with paket fails on core 2.1 - The licenseUrl and license elements cannot be used together

Tags: c#, .net-core, paket, dotnet-core-pack

dotnet pack with paket fails with **The licenseUrl and license elements cannot be used together**

This error is due to changes in dotnetCore SDKs between versions 2.1 and 2.2

Unfortunately, on my Jenkins agents there is only core 2.1 - I started nagging tools people to install 2.2 on them, but in the mean time, is there a way to make it work on 2.1?

I have to use Directory.build.propsas below, because it is part of a template for repositories on our new Jenkins infrastructure and it is overriden on checkout to set the versions

```
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <!-- NuGet -->
        <IsPackable>True</IsPackable>
        <PackageVersion>0.1.5-local</PackageVersion>
        <NuspecProperties>version=$(PackageVersion);licensePath=$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)LICENSE.txt</NuspecProperties>
        <PackageOutputPath>$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)Artifacts\NuGet\</PackageOutputPath>
        <PackageLicenseFile>LICENSE.txt</PackageLicenseFile>
        <!-- Build standards -->
        <OutputPath>bin\</OutputPath>
        <!-- Assembly information -->
        <FileVersion>0.1.5</FileVersion>
        <InformationalVersion>local build</InformationalVersion>
        <AssemblyVersion>0.1.5</AssemblyVersion>
        <Copyright>Some company</Copyright>
        <Company>Some company</Company>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <None Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)LICENSE.txt" Pack="true" PackagePath="$(PackageLicenseFile)"/>
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

I made a repro repo that shows the issue. I cannot edit Directory.Build.prop, only the csproj.

Is there a flag or maybe even older paket version that would work here?

https://github.com/qrzychu/paket_repro

https://github.com/fsprojects/Paket/issues/3657

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the braking changes in dotnet were in 2.1, so updating to 2.1.802 makes it magically work